# postfix loops back to myself email issue (was working before apt upgrade Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, domain, alias

Everything was working normal till apt upgrade on **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**, don't even remember what was upgraded, just routine, didn't change any config...

I really tried to fix, searched, but I don't know what to do...

The **ERROR**:

```
    Jun  9 23:47:40 newyork postfix/smtp[23810]: 18FB52F0FE3: 
    to=, relay=mail.raizen.top[127.0.1.1]:25, 
    delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, 
    status=bounced (mail for newyork.raizen.top loops back to myself
```

The **DNS** seems OK, was working fine.

[image]

The **main.cf**

```
    # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
    
    
    # Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
    # line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
    # is /etc/mailname.
    #myorigin = /etc/mailname
    
    smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
    biff = no
    
    # appending .domain is the MUA's job.
    append_dot_mydomain = no
    
    # Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
    #delay_warning_time = 4h
    
    readme_directory = no
    
    # See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
    # fresh installs.
    compatibility_level = 2
    
    
    
    # TLS parameters
    smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
    smtpd_tls_security_level = may
    
    smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
    smtp_tls_security_level = may
    smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
    
    
    smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
    myorigin = /etc/mailname
    relayhost = 
    mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
    mailbox_size_limit = 0
    recipient_delimiter = +
    inet_interfaces = all
    inet_protocols = all
    sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
    sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/dependent
    mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
    home_mailbox = Maildir/
    smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
    smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
    broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
    smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
    allow_percent_hack = no
    tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sni_map
    
    milter_default_action = accept
    smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
    non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
    
    # new config working
    mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain, mail.raizen.top
    alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
    alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
    #virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
    #virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
    message_size_limit = 32500000
    smtputf8_enable = no
```

The **alias_maps**

```
    raizen: raizen-newyork.raizen.top
    admin: raizen-newyork.raizen.top
    default: raizen-newyork.raizen.top
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mydestination` has `mail.raizen.top` but not `newyork.raizen.top`. Therefore, Postfix thinks this is outside of the local systems and tries to deliver it using the `newyork.raizen.top. MX 1 mail.raizen.top.` record, which resolves to the local loopback.

I guess it was probably working before for the reason `newyork.raizen.top` was either in `$myhostname` or `$mydomain` which has – for an unknown reason – changed during the update.

Comment: So simple, crazy, it works! Thank u